# Pypy No module named 'encodings' windows 10

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, pypy

So, I'm trying to run a python file with pypy3.7, but I'm getting a error even though it worked it the past. I have a working Python3.7, python3.9 and even python 2.7 added to path (default is 3.9).

(this works)

```
PS D:\pypy3.7-v7.3.3-win32> py --version
Python 3.9.2
```

the error I'm getting is:

```
PS D:\pypy3.7-v7.3.3-win32> .\pypy3.exe
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'
debug: OperationError:
debug:  operror-type: ModuleNotFoundError
debug:  operror-value: No module named 'encodings'
```

I have uninstalled and installed python3 since the last time it worked, but I have no idea if that's related

Edit: ended up installing pypy on an Ubuntu WSL which works fine

Answer (score 0):

PyPy is an alternative to Python interpreter. It does not share modules with Python.
To install modules specificaly for PyPy see [pypy docs here](https://doc.pypy.org/en/latest/install.html?highlight=modules#installing-more-modules)

Comment: it may also mislead you that the py command returns python 3. 
py.exe is the launcher for python, not pypy

Comment: The problem is that I can't launch anything using pypy, including a simple file that contains just `print("Hello World")` which I don't think depends on any specific module but I might be wrong.
Also tried running the `pypy -m ensurepip` which returned the same error

Comment: is there a reason you want to run using pypy?  did it work previously using pypy? if you do not need pypy specificaly you can just use python.

Comment: Nothing important. Just have some data crunching to do and thought it would be easier to make a simple python script. I can always make a c program but I felt like using python would be simpler (and I feel like it would take tens of minutes per run on normal python)

Comment: Ended up simply installing pypy on my Ubuntu WSL2 which works fine